# Upwards version of U+21b4

Tags: unicode

↴, or U+21b4 “Rightwards arrow with corner downwards“, points down. Is there a “rightwards arrow with corner *upwards*”?

Arrows seems to have every direction but that, and I could not find anything in Supplementary Arrows-A or -B, or even the [Wikipedia page on arrows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29#Arrows_in_Unicode).

Comment: I find this inconsistency really odd too...

Comment: WTF, Unicode. After so many languages, you got an "ornamental dingbats" section for cars and trains, but didn't bother to actually complete the arrows section!?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn’t. Some fonts contain such a symbol in the Private Use area.

If you try to find the symbol in Unicode by drawing it as [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/), the closest you can find are

⤴ U+2934 arrow pointing rightwards then curving upwards

⬏ U+2B0F rightwards arrow with tip upwards:

Answer (score 1):

⬑ How about this one? ⬑ It's leftwards but still pretty close :) http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/11025